# Custom symbol for this graph CPTPlotSymbol using coreplot

Tags: core-plot

How can I plot a graph like this using coreplot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least two plots—a scatter plot and a bar plot. Use the scatter plot to draw the connecting lines. Use the histogram style. Use a bar plot with custom bar fills or two bar plots (one for each fill color) to draw the boxes at each data point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sir, kindly any could provide more details. 1:Can CPTSymbol custom help giving it  starting point of the rect and end point go the rect with.  I see symbol are always drawn in the center.

Comment: I wouldn't use plot symbols at all. You'd have to calculate a different size for each one which would have to change while zooming in and out. Draw the connecting line with the scatter plot and the colored boxed with one or two (or however many different fills you need) bar plots.

Comment: Thanks. Will go ahead with Bar plot and see how it goes.